# Iniciar aplicação somente se uma url está em funcionamento (Online)

Tags: c#

Estou começando á tentar aprender um pouco na "marra", e queria saber se tem como fazer algum código que verifique se uma URL especifica está online, caso ela esteja a aplicação tem que iniciar normalmente, caso não, a aplicação deve ser fechada.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso em C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem sim Peeta !

```
    //Aqui você cria a requisição
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.sitepratestar.com.br");

    try{
         //Envia a requisição e recebe uma resposta ,  não recebendo é lançada uma exceção e o código segue pro catch
         HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

         //Testa se o status code da resposta foi 200 ,  que é retornado quando a url está online .

         if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
         {
               // Execute seu código...
               Console.WriteLine("URL ONLINE !!");
         }
         else
         {
               //status code diferente de OK, manda pro catch
               throw new Exception();
         }
   }
   catch
   {
       // Feche seu app aqui
   }
```